# How to access to the protected property of class in redefined interface method?

Tags: php, oop, interface, implements

I have a class which implements an interface.

```
interface Animal {
    public static function giveHug();
}

class Dog() implements Animal {

    protected $race;

    public function __construct($race)
    {
        $this->race = $race;
    }

    public static function giveHug()
    {
        return 'Kiss my friend' . $this->race;
    }
}
```

I get

> cannot use $this in non object context.

And I understand that, so how could I get Dog property in my redefined ***giveHug*** method ?
Do someone have any trick to help?
Thanks

Comment: Static methods can only call static methods/properties. Thus; remove static.

Comment: I have several classes using this interface. Do you have any trick to get this property?

Comment: if you will create some Dogs, how a static function will understand which race you want to use?

Comment: This is an limitation of `static` environment when you work in OOP. You should remove static from your method, but if it's mandatory for you to use it this way, so  do like this (it will only show "Kiss my friend" of last `Dog` instance):
`public function __construct($race) { $this->race = $race; self::$instance = $this; }`
`public static function giveHug() { return 'Kiss my friend ' . self::$instance->race; }`

Comment: `class Dog() ` -- that doesn't look like valid PHP. It would help if you extracted a [mcve] first, also to make sure you know what the problem really is. As others have mentioned, remove the `static` or describe why you think you need it. Also, I'd suggest you don't use `protected` members, make them `private` unless you have good (!) reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change code either way.

If `::giveHug` MUST be static, then you need to be able to provide the `Animal` to be hugged.

So this works:
*but is not so nice*

```
interface Animal
{
    public static function giveHug(Animal $animal);
}

class Dog implements Animal
{

    protected $race;

    public function __construct($race)
    {
        $this->race = $race;
    }

    public static function giveHug(Animal $animal)
    {
        return 'Kiss my friend ' . $animal->race;
    }
}

$dog = new Dog('WauWau');
echo Dog::giveHug($dog) . PHP_EOL;
// Kiss my friend WauWau
```

This is better:

```
interface Animal
{
    public static function getRace();

    public static function giveHug(Animal $animal);
}

class Dog implements Animal
{
    protected static $race;

    public function __construct($race)
    {
        self::$race = $race;
    }

    public static function getRace()
    {
        return self::$race;
    }

    public static function giveHug(Animal $animal)
    {
        return 'Kiss my friend ' . $animal::getRace();
    }
}

$dog = new Dog('WauWau');
echo Dog::giveHug($dog) . PHP_EOL;
// Kiss my friend WauWau
```

---

**BUT** now to the topic: does it make sense?

No.
And this is a really good example.
You do not tell a "static" animal (or dog) to give a hug.
You would want to tell a specific (object) animal to give a hug.

So this makes more sense:

```
interface Animal
{
    public function giveHug();
}

class Dog implements Animal
{
    protected $race;

    public function __construct($race)
    {
        $this->race = $race;
    }

    public function giveHug()
    {
        return 'Kiss my friend ' . $this->race;
    }
}

$dog = new Dog('WauWau');
// Note: we call $dog to give hug. So the ONE dog =)
echo $dog->giveHug() . PHP_EOL;
// Kiss my friend WauWau
```

EDIT: the example

```
$dog = new Dog('WauWau');
echo Dog::giveHug($dog) . PHP_EOL;
```

is more like a "Hey, all Dogs out there ... give a hug to this (Animal $dog)".
*And there are cases this makes sense. But in this case - not =)*

Comment: Thanks to take time to explain this. I just create example of dog. the context is little bit different but i understand what you mean. I would still try your trick to see